# Radeon HD 6290 terrible performance on a certified laptop

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I bought Asus K53U laptop, which is Ubuntu certified with pre-installed 11.10. The graphic card is Radeon HD 6290 but 720p playback is terrible. Even page scrolling in Firefox is very laggy. Proprietary drivers are installed by default.

How is this  possible, why is the laptop Ubuntu certified if the performance is poor? Any solution to this?

I just did `apt-get autoremove`, and after that, this message came out in terminal:

```
Error inserting vesafb (/lib/modules/3.0.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/video/vesafb.ko): 
No such device
```

Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

update your drivers from the command line CTRL+ALT+T

1. install the ATI drivers in the terminal with the following command

   `sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle`
2. You may also need to reinstall the updates again:

   `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates`
3. It can be a pain I know from experience. Sometimes I have had to go back the beginning by cleaning out fglrx (`sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`) and starting afresh.

Comment: fglrx already installed, but fglrx-amdcclete not found

Comment: fglrx-amdcccle is already the newest version.
fglrx-amdcccle set to manually installed.